# Uso de variable no asignada

Tags: c#

Tengo este código en c# y no puedo ejecutarlo debido al error de variable no asignada (variable total).
Tengo el mismo en visual basic y no genera errores.
Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const byte tasa_anual = 36;
        decimal totalInteres, interes, capital, total;
        totalInteres = 0;
        
        byte meses;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar capital inicial: ");
        capital = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar cantidad de meses: ");
        meses = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mes |  Saldo     | Interes   | Saldo total  ");

        for (int x = 1; x <= meses; x++)
        {
            capital = total;
            interes = capital * tasa_anual / 12 / 100;
            total = capital + interes;
            totalInteres += interes;
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}", x, capital, interes, total);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total de intereses: ${0}", totalInteres);

    }
}
```

Comment: Visual basic es mas laxo con variables no inicializadas, por eso no te daba error. En C# las variables deben inicializarse antes de ser usadas.

Comment: Podrias poner exactamente el mensaje que recibes y donde lo marca? quizas solo necesites definir `decimal total = 0;` cuando declaras la variable en lugar de ponerla junto al resto

Comment: al inicializarlo en 0, el calculo total queda en 0. Pero estoy casi segura que es un error de calculo

Answer (score 1):

aparentemente tu problema es por que tu variable valor, trae un dato que es null. Inicializa tu variable en 0, para que no te muestre ese error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const byte tasa_anual = 36;
        decimal totalInteres, interes, capital, total;
        totalInteres = 0;
        total = 0; // He incluido esta linea, para el cambio
        
        byte meses;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar capital inicial: ");
        capital = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar cantidad de meses: ");
        meses = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mes |  Saldo     | Interes   | Saldo total  ");

        for (int x = 1; x <= meses; x++)
        {
            capital = total;
            interes = capital * tasa_anual / 12 / 100;
            total = capital + interes;
            totalInteres += interes;
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}", x, capital, interes, total);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total de intereses: ${0}", totalInteres);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro, utilizas la variable `total` antes de que tenga un valor. Me imagino que el error salta en la línea dónde `capital = total;`

Debes inicializarla, por ejemplo `total = 0;` tal como verás en el código.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const byte tasa_anual = 36;
        decimal totalInteres, interes, capital, total;
        totalInteres = 0;
        total = 0;
        byte meses;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar capital inicial: ");
        capital = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar cantidad de meses: ");
        meses = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mes |  Saldo     | Interes   | Saldo total  ");

        for (int x = 1; x <= meses; x++)
        {
            capital = total;
            interes = capital * tasa_anual / 12 / 100;
            total = capital + interes;
            totalInteres += interes;
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}    {1}    {2}    {3}", x, capital, interes, total);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total de intereses: ${0}", totalInteres);

    }
}
```